# Манипуляция date в c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, дата, eval

Я могу вывести в `gridview` дату через `<%# Eval("DateStart") %>`, но мне необходимо вывести разницу между сегодня и указаной датой.

```
<%# DateTime.Today - Eval("DateStart") %>
```

Что-то типа такого, но этот вариант не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(DateTime.Today - (DateTime)Eval("DateStart")).Days
```

Comment: Увы, но не работает. 
Пробую `<%# (DateTime.Today - Eval("DateStart")).Days %>`

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron, а я должен угадывать, как именно оно не работает? Где текст ошибки?

Comment: Логично. Сейчас посмотрю

Comment: приведения типов мож не хватает, может Now лучше подходит. (DateTime.Now - (DateTime)Eval("DateStart")).Days

Comment: @SanŚ́́́́Ý́́́́Ś́́́́ ага, так и должно быть.